# Creating default metal library from ios framework

Tags: swift, bundle, ios-frameworks

I am creating a framework which includes several metal files, while creating default library using `device?.makeDefaultLibrary()`
(when this framework is embedded in a project), application is crashing. It turns out that without specifying `Bundle()` to `makeDefaultLibrary()` it only searches for library in main bundle, but as per requirement compiler should search for library in embedded framework's bundle (a **.metallib** file is being generated while creating Framework).

I have tried specifying **bundle** as below:

A.

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let bundleLib = try device?.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: frameworkBundle)
```

B.

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myframework")
let bundleLib = try device?.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: frameworkBundle)
```

Still the application is crashing, I have also noticed that in both the above methods **frameworkBundle** is returned as nil.

Answer (score 0):

Offering this as an answer, and more than happy to delete it if it doesn't help.

I have a library of `CIKernels` that are text files with a `.cikernel` suffix. These are contained in a framework and I created a function to open them as needed by specifying the bundle name like this:

```
let myBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: "com.mycompany.myframework")
let kernelPath = (myBundle?.path(forResource: "cikernels", ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + named + ".cikernel"
```

In your case, I think you need *"com.myframework"*.

Basically, from what I see in your question and [the](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/2177054-makedefaultlibrary) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle), it looks like a `Bundle` is an `NSObject` (about the most basic object you can have and you (properly done) code is allowing a `nil` return if you are passing in the correct bundle.

See if this works for you. Good luck!

**EDIT:**

A second thought - my creation of a Bundle uses `Bundle.init(identifier:)`. Maybe that's all you need instead of my "overkill" method? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let metalLibraryPath = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "metallib")!
let bundleLib = device?.makeLibrary(filepath:metalLibraryPath)
```